# Is there any software that can make drawing transitions for us?

Tags: animation, pixel, pixel-art, sprite

I want to start a 2d game containing pixel sprite as characters. To make a walking animation, I know I need to simultanously put different sprite to make it seem like he walk and I can make it more or less fluid by adding or removing  sprites. I know I also think I need at least two images. My question is, even if I already think the answer is no, for a pixel character sprite, is there any free software that can make different character pose based on one or two images ? (look the images to clearly understand). If not, is there any simpler way to animate a pixel character sprite ?[[image: cx]
[image]

Comment: The term you might want to search for is 'tweening'.

Comment: Yes software like this exist. Is it worth the effort? Hardly.

Comment: Frame challenge: Many game engines now support 2D FK & IK rigging (I know both Unity and Unreal do) so that all you really need is a resting pose sprite sheet and some basic understanding of IK and FK and you're all set - if you fee like drawing / painting your tweens is too much work, why not just rig your 2D sprite characters and animate that way?

Comment: I don't thin kthat would do what I want. See, I know about this stuff, but I want pixel sprite. If I'm getting this right, what you suggest would result in rotating an arm for example, which would result in rotating my pixels as well, and I want them to stay at a 0° rotation. I don't know if that make sense.

Comment: It does, but if it's desirable, there's an easy answer: post-processing can allow a pixelation to be applied to keep an "8-bit feel" - you wouldn't have down-to-the-pixel perfection or art direction, but if your goal is to avoid what you might regard as onerous pixel-painting tweening work, it could suffice.

Comment: If the drawing can be made as vector and then convert it to sprite, you can tween those vectors first, and then convert.
If you start from raster sprites, no software can do that easily. It would imply one of this options:
- The software has to guess what is moving.
- The software blends those images without trying to guess.
Guessing would imply an algorithm or AI that can produce weird results. Some morphing software let you choose reference points for blending, but that wouldn't be much of a solution either.